# Fortran 2003 does not allow this intrinsic procedure [BESSEL_J0]

Tags: fortran, fortran2003

I would like to use the `bessel_j0` function in Fortran 2003 (the version installed on the supercomputer I use), but during the compilation of my source code I encounter the following warning:

> warning #7416: Fortran 2003 does not allow this intrinsic procedure. 
>   [BESSEL_J0]

Then what?

Does it mean I cannot use it at all? Or can I call it any other way?

Comment: What makes you think the version installed is specifically 2003? And what commands did you use to compile the code?

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Almost no-one follows the [tag:fortan2003] specific tag here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, this is a warning, not an error. If there is nothing more following, the compilation should proceed OK.

This kind of warning happens when you explicitly request to compile your program as Fortran 2003. So just don't that!

Function `BESSEL_J0` is from Fortran 2008. Just remove any `-stand f03` or `-std=f2003` or similar options. Or at least increase the standard from 03 to 08 in those flags.

I can't more specific, because you did not tell us your compiler version and the flags you use, but the warning appears to be from Intel Fortran.